# unknown action type vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using vuex modules and I'm trying to call Actions but I get an error. However, everything works if left in the vuex global storage.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
    
export default createStore({
  state: {
    clickCountCart: 0,
    clickCountHeart: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    incrementClickCountCart(state) {
      state.clickCountCart++;
    },
    incrementClickCountHeart(state) {
      state.clickCountHeart++;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    incrementClickCountCart(context) {
      context.commit('incrementClickCountCart');
    },
    incrementClickCountHeart(context) {
      context.commit('incrementClickCountHeart');
    },
  },
});
```

Component:

```html
<li><i class="bx bx-heart" @click="incrementClickHeart"></i></li>
<li><i class="bx bx-search"></i></li>
<li><i class="bx bx-cart" @click="incrementClickCart"></i></li>
```

```js
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Goods',
  props: [],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['incrementClickCountCart']),
    incrementClickCart() {
      this.incrementClickCountCart();
    },
    ...mapActions(['incrementClickCountHeart']),
    incrementClickHeart() {
      this.incrementClickCountHeart();
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: "I get an error" - which error? Please, list it entirely. "left in the vuex global storage" - in  which way?

Comment: Error: [vuex] unknown action type: incrementClickCountCart; when I use one file index.js for all data instead modules: counter.js, etc.

Comment: Please, clarify, does this happen when you use modules or when you not use them? The question doesn't show the modules. The code that you already posted looks ok and is expected to work

Comment: When I use one file index.js everything works fine. For some reason the problem is only with this module

Comment: this is not a module, it is it's own independent store which is evident by the use of `createStore`, so maybe that's your problem. You need to make it a proper module.  Review the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-local-state) for that.